# LINQ. Is linking .includes possible to avoid joins on large datasets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am building an n-layered application using a Repository/Unit of Work pattern, but I'm having troubles reading properties of related entities as they are not loading. I have identified the issue to be caused by Lazy-loading. An simplified example could be trying to retrive the Auther of a Book in the code below, as both the Author and Publisher properties of Book are both null.

In general I'm intrigued by Lazy-Loading, as this (as I understand it) should reduce the amount of data being transferred. The is particular interesting to me as I'm not always using all properties or collections in my Razor Pages.
That said I'm not sure this is a good strategy, and are considering to change the whole architecture away from the Repository/Unit of Work pattern. I have not decided yet.

```
public Author 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Publisher> Publishers {get; set;}
}

public Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Author> Authors {get; set;}
    public Publisher Publisher {get; set;}
}

public Publisher
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Author> Authors {get; set;}
}
```

Back to the problem. First I tried applying `.Include(p=>p.Author)` or `.Load(p=>p.Author)`, but have realized this is not possible after `.ToListAsync()` which I call in the `GetAllAsync()' method in the generic repository.

Now I'm considering to Inject `DbContext` either directly into my Razor Pages or in the Service-layer and then chain `Include()` calls e.i.

```
_context.DBSetBooks<Book>.Include(p => p.Publisher).Where(p => p.Publisher.Name == "Manning").Include(p => p.Author);
```

The idea above is to reduce the amount of data transferred, or did I misunderstand it completely?

I not too fond of Injecting the `DBContext` in each Razor pages - thats why I choose the Repository/Unit of Work design pattern in the first place.. If I still want Lazy-Loading should I then try a DDD-pattern instead?

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: `Include` is only used for eager loading, not generating JOINSs. Those are generated by the relations between entities by the ORM itself. As for Repository and UoW, you don't need them. A DbSet is already a Repository, a DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. If you try to reimplement the patterns, you'll only create bugs *and* break the UoW functionality

Comment: As for lazy loading, quite often it *increases* the data that's loaded and the overhead due to the N+1 problem. Instead of executing 1 query that returns all necessary data, you have 1 query that returns only the root objects and N queries to load each object as it's accessed. That's bad

Comment: Besides the comments you should really understand by @PanagiotisKanavos, this part of the question: "The is particular interesting to me as I'm not always using all properties or collections in my Razor Pages" tells me that you should **not** be using lazy loading nor `Include`, but rather create ViewModels with the necessary data and `Select` that instead

Comment: LINQ allows you to load *only* the properties you want, nothing more. There's no reason to load entire entities. There's no reason to use patterns that were introduced in 2000 to load entire entities in J2EE. Think of a DbContext as the data service for a bounded context in DDD. There's no reason to have one DbContext for the entire application, mapping the entire database. It makes sense to create a *specialized* repository to ease access to the specialized DbContext. A generic context though, is useless. A DbSet already provides that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the amount of transferred data you have to reduce .include, so make your queries like this (it is just idea):

At first create class that has only the fields you need:

```
public class BookInfo
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
  public string AuthorName {get; set;}
 public string PublisherName {get; set;}
.... and so on
}
```

Get list of books using query like this:

```
 var books = await _context.Set<Book>()
.Where(p => p.Publisher.Name == "Manning")
.Select (b =>  new  BookInfo {
Id = b.Id,
AuthorName=b.Author.Name,
PublisherName=b.Publisher.Name,
....and so on

}).ToArrayAsync();
```

Another possiblility is that you put partial class Book in a separate file with extra fields  like this

```
public partial class Book 
{
 [NotMapped]
  public string AuthorName {get; set;}
[NotMapped]
 public string PublisherName {get; set;}
}
```

In this case you can use the same class Book instead of BookInfo:

```
.Select ( b => new  Book {
Id = b.Id,
AuthorName=b.Author.Name,
PublisherName=b.Publisher.Name,
....and so on

}).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: `.Set<>()` can only be used if the entity is already configured. In that case, why not use the `Books` property directly? Nothing is gained by using `Set<>()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't see your full dbcontext this is why I am using Set. But usually  I would use Books.